# AWS Beanstalk couldn't create nginx config file at the deployment automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a Django API application that is deployed on AWS Beanstalk Amazon Linux 2 (Python 3.8). In a part of my application, the user should be able to upload a file through API.

Nginx, on default, is returning CORS error to the user when the uploaded file is bigger than 3 MB and logging 'user tries to upload huge file' in the Nginx log.

The only solution which works for me is creating the bellow configuration file and reloading the Nginx:

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`:

```
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

and then:
`sudo service nginx reload`

I have done this procedure manually by connecting to the EC2 which is the host of my beanstalk application via SSH. I want to automate this procedure to be done at every deployment and every instance.

I have created a file called `nginx_max_upload.config` file in `.ebextensions` folder which is located in the root of my project:
`nginx_max_upload.config`:

```
files:
/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        client_max_body_size 50M

commands:
  reload_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"
    ignoreErrors: true
```

My problem is, the above code didn't create the file I want in the specified directory. When I changed the directory to another directory like `/usr/local/bin/proxy.conf`, the file would be successfully created but it can't create the config file in the Nginx configuration folder.

I guess the problem might be from the permissions but I don't know how to grant the needed permission to the deployment agent.

Also, I have tried these two solutions but none of them works:

1. I have tried to create the config file in another folder and then, move it via `mv` command to the right directory but it didn't work.
2. Also, I have tried to put the creation code in the predeply hook and put manual `echo` commands in my code. I saw all of my `echo` commands output in the beanstalk logs but it didn't do anything (nor creating the file in the nginx configuration neither moving it from somewhere else to the configuration folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Amazon Linux 2 (AL2), your configuration files are incorrect. They used to work in AL1, but for AL2, they are in different place and have different format as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Thus could have the following `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf` (not in `.ebextensions`) with content:

```
client_max_body_size 50M;
```